# google maps dragend event undefined while click works

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, events

hi so I'm trying to get a hold of the dragend event

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(map,'dragend',function(event) {
//stuff
});
```

now the odd thing is when i use this event listener "event" is undefined, but if i for instance replace "dragend" with "mouseup", then i get a defined event in my function .  does anybody know why this is and how i can get get a hold of the dragend event?

Comment: what functionality you need to achieve in dragend event..?

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Map) the dragend event doesn't have any arguments to its callback function:

> dragend
>   Arguments:  None
>   This event is fired when the user stops dragging the map.

You can use other functions inside the callback when dragging ends (i.e. `map.getCenter()` will get the new center of the map)